# What is the correct JNA mapping for XGetInputFocus

Tags: java, x11, jna

I am trying to map X11 `XGetInputFocus` through JNA. The original method signature is

```
XGetInputFocus(Display *display, Window *focus_return, int *revert_to_return)
```

Which I assumed could be mapped to the following in Java, using the already defined JNA platform types.

```
void XGetInputFocus(Display display, Window focus_return, IntByReference revert_to_return);
```

Which correlates to the recommendation described in the [documentation](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md). I now invoke it using the following code

```
final X11 XLIB = X11.INSTANCE;
Window current = new Window();
Display display = XLIB.XOpenDisplay(null);
if (display != null) {
   IntByReference revert_to_return = new IntByReference();
   XLIB.XGetInputFocus(display, current, revert_to_return);
}
```

However, it crashes the JVM with

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x285b7]  XGetInputFocus+0x57
```

What am I missing?

Comment: May be in the declaration of `XGetInputFocus`
you should use [`WindowByReference`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/unix/X11.WindowByReference.html)
instead of `Window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the native X11 function

```
XGetInputFocus(Display *display, Window *focus_return, int *revert_to_return)
```

the parameter `Window *focus_return` is used to *return* a `Window`.
JNA implemented [`Window`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/unix/X11.Window.html) very much like an immutable type,
because in C language it is defined by [`typedef XID Window;`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libx11-ddefs.html#AEN3448).
Therefore type `Window*` in C needs to be mapped to `WindowByReference` in JNA.
(This is essentially the same reason why `int*` in C needed to be mapped
to `IntByReference` in JNA.)

Then the extended `X11` interface can look like this:

```
public interface X11Extended extends X11 {
    X11Extended INSTANCE = (X11Extended) Native.loadLibrary("X11", X11Extended.class);

    void XGetInputFocus(Display display, WindowByReference focus_return, IntByReference revert_to_return);
}
```

And your code should be modified accordingly:

```
X11Extended xlib = X11Extended.INSTANCE;
WindowByReference current_ref = new WindowByReference();
Display display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(null);
if (display != null) {
    IntByReference revert_to_return = new IntByReference();
    xlib.XGetInputFocus(display, current_ref, revert_to_return);
    Window current = current_ref.getValue();
    System.out.println(current);
}
```

Now the program doesn't crash anymore.
For me it prints `0x3c00605`.

Comment: Thank you, I am still trying to figure out why this difference is necessary however. For a primitive type it makes sense but an object isn't immutable unless you make it so? But I'm only scratching the surface with JNA.

Comment: @Xunkar I have added some more explanation about this.